# Why does my Spring ModelAttribute return from a form with a null reference?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, modelattribute

So I'm trying to make a small Spring MVC application to learn the ropes on Spring and now I find myself with a rather bizarre problem. I have two model classes: `Game` and `Publisher` with a bidirectional relation between them. Whenever i try to pass a `Game` object as a ModelAttribute through a html form (on a JSP page with the relevant Spring tags), it always return with a nullpointer where the reference to the related `Publisher` object used to be. I suspect it has something to do with the fact that Spring can only pass one ModelAttribute to the view. Does anyone know why exactly this happens and how i can make it so that the right `Publisher` object gets returned from the view?

Relevant code:

Game class:

```
public class Game {

    private final long id;
    @NotNull
    private String title;
    @NotNull
    private Genre genre;
    @NotNull
    private Date releaseDate;
    @NotNull
    private Publisher publisher;

    public Game() {
        this.id = IdRegistry.GAMEIDREGISTRY.getId();
        this.title = null;
        this.genre = null;
        this.releaseDate = null;
        this.publisher = null;
    }   

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public Genre getGenre() {
        return genre;
    }

    public void setGenre(Genre genre) {
        this.genre = genre;
    }

    public Date getReleaseDate() {
        return releaseDate;
    }

    public void setReleaseDate(Date releaseDate) {
        this.releaseDate = releaseDate;
    }

    public Publisher getPublisher() {
        return publisher;
    }

    public void setPublisher(Publisher publisher) {
        this.publisher = publisher;
    }
}
```

Publisher class:

```
public class Publisher {

    private final long id;
    @NotNull
    private String name;
    @NotNull
    private List<Game> games;

    public Publisher() {
        this.id = IdRegistry.PUBLISHERIDREGISTRY.getId();
        this.name = null;
        this.games = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public Publisher(String name) {
        this.id = IdRegistry.PUBLISHERIDREGISTRY.getId();
        this.name = name;
        this.games = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public Publisher(long id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.games = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public Publisher(String name, List<Game> games) {
        this.id = IdRegistry.PUBLISHERIDREGISTRY.getId();
        this.name = name;
        this.games = games;
    }

    public Publisher(long id, String name, List<Game> games) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.games = games;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<Game> getGames() {
        return games;
    }

    public void setGames(List<Game> games) {
        this.games = games;
    }

    public void addGame(Game game) {
        games.add(game);
    }

    public void addGames(Collection<Game> games) {
        this.games.addAll(games);
    }

    public void removeGame(Game game) {
        games.remove(game);
        games.sort(null);
    }

    public void removeGames(Collection<Game> games) {
        this.games.removeAll(games);
    }
}
```

Relevant controller methods:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/edit/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getEditForm(@PathVariable long id) {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("/game/editgame");
        model.addObject("game", service.getGame(id));
        model.addObject("genres", service.getAllGenres());
        model.addObject("publishers", service.getAllPublishers());
        return model;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/edit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String editGame(@Valid @ModelAttribute("game") Game game, BindingResult bResult, SessionStatus status) {
        if(bResult.hasErrors())
            return "addgame";
        service.updateGame(game.getId(), game.getTitle(), game.getGenre(), game.getReleaseDate(), game.getPublisher().getId());
        status.setComplete();
        return "redirect:/game.htm";
    }
```

View form:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page session="true" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/jsp/head.jsp">
        <jsp:param name="title" value="Edit games here" />
    </jsp:include>

    <body>
        <%@include file="/WEB-INF/jsp/header.jsp" %>
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Edit games here</h1>
            <c:url var="post_url"  value="/game/edit.htm" />
            <form:form id="gameform" role="form" method="post" modelAttribute="game" action="${post_url}">

                <form:input path="id" type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="${sessionScope.game.id}"/>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="title">Title</label>
                    <form:input path="title" type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="title" value="${sessionScope.game.title}" placeholder="Title" required="required"/>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="genre">Genre</label>
                    <form:select path="genre" class="form-control" id="genre" name="genre" value="${sessionScope.game.genre}" placeholder="Genre" required="required">
                        <c:forEach var="genre" items="${genres}">
                            <form:option value="${genre}"/>
                        </c:forEach>                   
                    </form:select>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="releaseDate">Release Date</label>
                    <fmt:formatDate var="fmtDate" value="${sessionScope.game.releaseDate}" type="date" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" />
                    <form:input path="releaseDate" type="date" class="form-control" id="releaseDate" name="releaseDate" value="${fmtDate}" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" required="required"/>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="publisher">Publisher</label>
                    <form:select path="publisher" class="form-control" id="publisher" name="publisher" value="${sessionScope.game.publisher}" placeholder="Publisher" required="required">
                        <c:forEach var="publisher" items="${publishers}">
                            <form:option value="${publisher.name}"/>
                        </c:forEach>                    
                    </form:select>
                </div>

                <input class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" value="Update">
            </form:form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Spring should manage obj rekations in model without problems. Are you sure that the objs you are passing to the model are properly set? Have you checked it with debug? Additionally, what is your "service"? Does it take objs from DB? Are you sure you're not stepping in lazy initialization issues?

Comment: To answer your questions in order: yes, yes, a facade that manages adding and removing of objects, not yet and not that i know of.